# Does using Array.slice(0, -1) to pop back cause a memory leak

Tags: javascript, arrays

According to Mozilla docs, .slice() creates a shallow copy. Thus I am wondering about the following situation

```
function foo(){
 let arr = [0,1,2,3,4]
 return arr.slice(0, -1) // returns [0,1,2,3]
}
```

Since the returned array is a shallow copy of the underlying array of [0,1,2,3,4] with a reduced size that ends at 3 instead of 4, what happens? Does either:

The last item in the array gets garbage collected once arr falls out of scope, leaving [0,1,2,3] in memory (No memory leak)

OR

(Assuming the size never increases again) Since the returned reference still points to the underlying array, the entire thing lives on as [0,1,2,3,4], but is only viewable as [0,1,2,3] through the object referring to it due to the size restriction (Memory leak, item 4 lives on)

Comment: You don't need to worry about memory leaks in Javascript; it is a garbage collected language.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "underlying array", `slice` returns a **copy** not a view. It does create a new array (of length 4), the original `arr` with its 5 values is garbage-collected.